# How to get string input from a socket in D?

Tags: sockets, d

I'm using this code to listen to a port:

```
int start(){
        ushort port = 61888;
        listener = new TcpSocket();
        assert(listener.isAlive);
        listener.blocking = false;
        listener.bind(new InternetAddress(port));
        listener.listen(10);
        writefln("Listening on port %d.", port);

        enum MAX_CONNECTIONS = 60;
        auto socketSet = new SocketSet(MAX_CONNECTIONS + 1);
        Socket[] reads;
        while (true)
        {
            socketSet.add( listener);

            foreach (sock; reads)
                socketSet.add(sock);

            Socket.select(socketSet, null, null);

           

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

As far as I know, sockets interact with the bytes as they are. I want to find a way how to convert these bytes (which are essentially SQL requests) to strings. How can I do so, providing that input is in UTF-8, which is an encoding using variable size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a few questions here.

> How do I get chars from bytes?

1. cast them with `cast(char[]) st`. This aliases the bytes, giving you a slice of the exact same data, and doesn't require new allocation. You are not yet assuming that the bytes are valid UTF-8, but autodecoding or other parts of your program might complain if they aren't. You can run it by `std.utf.validate` if you want.
2. do basically the same thing with `std.string.assumeUTF(st)`, which at least also asserts on invalid UTF *in debug builds only.*

> How do I get a string from char[]?

You can unsafely alias the `char[]` with `std.exception.assumeUnique(st)`, or you can allocate an immutable copy with `st.idup` or `std.utf.toUTF8(st)`.

> What if my fixed buffer of bytes contains invalid UTF-8 -- because it got cut off?

If that's a risk you can use low level `std.utf` tools (`decodeFront` and catching `UTFException` is one way) to peel off the valid UTF-8 and then check if you have remaining bytes, or to check that the end of the input is valid UTF-8.

> How do I know if I've gotten a complete SQL statement with my fixed buffer socket I/O?

Instead of just passing the raw SQL statement over the line, you can define a network protocol that includes information like statement size, or that has 'end of statement' markers that you can read for.

I've a [cheat sheet](https://d.minimaltype.com/index.cgi/wiki?name=string+type+conversions) for string type conversions, which links to a file of more elaborate unittests.

Comment: Last question: how to get bytes from a port? I'm quite uncertain.

Comment: @Tannenfels call `.receive` on the Socket with a `ubyte[]` buffer. I've got an example [here](https://d.minimaltype.com/index.cgi/wiki?name=echo+serial)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

import std.exception: assumeUnique;

string s = assumeUnique (cast(char[])ubyteArray);